# Chart.js: Chart data only showing when window resizes

Tags: javascript, ajax, charts, chart.js

I call the function, then set a timeout.

[image: I just call the function]

Comment: can you provide some of your codes?

Comment: @jana I already added a scnsht.

Comment: Did you tried to create the chart after that the AJax request was succesfull?

Comment: @Steven it worked!

Comment: So the solution is to wait after the AJAX request is successful?

Comment: Put the chart on the success().